# planned contrast with **emmeans** on interaction term in mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, contrasts, lsmeans

I think this is simple: I want to test if a treatment (that I know a priori does something) is stronger in one group vs. the other (in the presence of random effects). This seems like it should be straightforward with **emmeans**, but I'm struggling to find the example that matches my use case and would love a pointer. Below is a simulated dataset and where I got to so far...

How do I compare the strength of treatment between my two groups `f2 == "A"` and `f2 == "B"`?

I am partly asking for the right **emmeans** syntax, but also not sure which p-value correction is appropriate in a situation like this.
Thanks!

```
# load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

# simulate data
# this is a slight modification from glmer.nb test data from Ben Bolker
dd <- expand.grid(f1 = factor(1:2), # changed to 2 from 3; this is treatment 
                  f2 = LETTERS[1:2] # this is the "group"
                  , g = 1:9 # random effect
                  , rep = 1:600
                  , KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE)
# in documentation, BB didn't simulate `mu` as a function of `g` but I will
# this avoids singular fits
summary(mu <- 5*(-4 + with(dd, as.integer(f1) + 4*as.numeric(f2) + g/5)))
dd$y <- rnbinom(nrow(dd), mu = mu, size = 0.5)
str(dd)

# define and fit model
my_formula <- "y ~ f1:f2 + f1 + f2 + (1|g)"

my_mod <- glmer.nb(formula = my_formula
                   , data = dd
                   # , control = glmerControl(maxit = 1e6)
)

# what I want to say is whether the treatment("f1") is stronger for one group 
# vs. the other (i.e `f2 == "A"` vs. `f2 == "B"`)

# I thought the way to do this (in a planned contrast framework) might be to 
# estimate marginal means (with `emmeans::emmeans`) and then calculate adjusted
# p-values for the interaction term of interest here

# my first stab was this:

emm_first<-emmeans(my_mod
                   ,  trt.vs.ctrl~ f1|f2)

# then, to get the contrast
contrast(emm_first
         , method = "trt.vs.ctrl")

# which returns 0s. Is this right (and I simulated wrong), or am I using emmeans 
# wrong?
```

**UPDATE**

@RussLenth suggested modifying the last line to

```
contrast(emm_first
        , method = "trt.vs.ctrl"
         , by = NULL)
```

Which returns great-looking ouptput:

```
$emmeans
 contrast      estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 f12 A - f11 A    0.377 0.0277 Inf  13.603  <.0001
 f11 B - f11 A    1.124 0.0276 Inf  40.692  <.0001
 f12 B - f11 A    1.252 0.0276 Inf  45.385  <.0001

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 3 tests 

$contrasts
 contrast                      estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 (f12 - f11 B) - (f12 - f11 A)   -0.248 0.0389 Inf  -6.374  <.0001

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

Final question: is this "dunnettx" p-value the best choice for asking my question?

Comment: emm_first still "remembers" f2 as the by variable. try adding by = NULL to the contrast call.

Comment: BTW, I wonder why you named the factors "f1" and "f2" rather than "treatment" and "group". I don't think it improves an analysis to make the variable names abstract. In fact, it puts up a barrier in interpreting the results.

Comment: @RussLenth Thanks! When adding `by = NULL` I get an output that looks right! Is this a sensible p-value for a planned contrast? FWIW I agree on variable names. I basically copy-pasted the example given in `?lme4::glmer.nb` to avoid thinking too hard about the simulation :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce the results here exactly because the random-number seed is not given. But there is some confusion here because, due to the two-sided formula, `emm_first` is a *list* of two objects. If I understand the question, we want the contrasts only of the second one -- i.e., a contrast of contrasts:

```
> contrast(emm_first[[2]]
+          , method = "trt.vs.ctrl"
+          , by = NULL)
 contrast                      estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 (f12 - f11 B) - (f12 - f11 A)   -0.221 0.0392 Inf  -5.631  <.0001

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

This is an example of an *interaction contrast*. Below are the means and the required interaction contrast:

```
> (EMM <- emmeans(my_mod, ~ f1 * f2))
 f1 f2 emmean     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1  A    2.28 0.0580 Inf      2.17      2.40
 2  A    2.69 0.0580 Inf      2.57      2.80
 1  B    3.37 0.0579 Inf      3.25      3.48
 2  B    3.55 0.0579 Inf      3.43      3.66

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> contrast(EMM, interaction = "trt.vs.ctrl")
 f1_trt.vs.ctrl f2_trt.vs.ctrl estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 2 - 1          B - A            -0.221 0.0392 Inf  -5.631  <.0001

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

Note that the same result is obtained.

This is discussed more fully in the [vignette on interactions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html) in the **emmeans** package.

*Side note:* Due to fairly widespread confusion resulting from follow-up analyses when a two-sided formula was used, versions after 1.7.4-1 will just do the contrast on the first one in the list (in this case, *not* the one desired), with a message.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which fully addresses how to use **emmeans** to obtain the relevant contrast. Could you also comment on the correct p-value computation (which method is preferred for this and why)?

Comment: Really appreciate all the support you give on this site to help people learn your package, it's super. Thank you!

Comment: In the vignette, it seems contrasts are considered post-hoc, I'd like to leverage any power I can from having a well-formulated question :-). What is the least-conservative, appropriate p-value for a pre-hoc planned comparison of an interaction term? Thanks!!

Comment: The one you have. It is just one test, so there is no multiplicity adjustment. There is no law that says you have to do an ANOVA first -- those really are most useful for model selection, and their importance for testing (as opposed to just summarizing the contributions of model terms) is over-rated, IMO.